# Обновление данных в реальном времени

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что данные должны обновляться в реальном времени, а не после обновления странице, понимаю, что это нужно сделать при помощи ajax, но с ним не очень хорошо знаком. Есть данные, которые получены из БД и хранятся в php переменной. Игра по типу рулетки, юзер нажимает старт и делает ставку, из БД показано общее кол-во игр, и общая сумма всех ставок, мой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы эти данные обновлялись при их изменении без перезагрузки?

```html
<div class="tab_content">
  <div class="tab_left_content">
   <p  class="totalBidGame">{!! $TotalBidLuckyGame !!}</p>       </div>
  <div class="tab_right_content"  style="display:none">
     <p class="totalGame">{!! $LuckyGame !!}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это делается при помощи ajax. Если возникнут сложности с конкретной реализацией - обращайтесь

Comment: Я знаю, что через Ajax))
Собственно, в этом и вопрос, как это реализовать?

Comment: Для начала, Вам нужно разобраться, что такое ajax, как с помощью него делать запросы и обрабатывать ответы.

Comment: У вас очень общий вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял